# Mysqli insert id not working

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code so far:

```
$con= mysqli_connect("*********","*********","*********","***********");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }

$queryorder = 'INSERT INTO `order`
    (`orderone`, `ordertwo`, `orderthree`)
VALUES
        ("'.$one.'","'.$two.'","'.$three.'")';

$result = mysqli_query($con, $queryorder);
        if (!$result) {
        printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
        }
```

i already tried the following putting "mysqli_insert_id(); after my query:

```
$orderid = mysqli_insert_id();
```

and did a var dump of it to see the value of "$orderid" but i keep getting NULL

```
var_dump($orderid);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Wrong Syntax**

1:change VALUE to VALUES

2:include a semi colon

```
$queryorder = "INSERT INTO `order`(`orderone`, `ordertwo`, `orderthree`) VALUES
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

```
        ('$one','$two','$three')";
```

Also
**change**

```
if (false === $result) {
        printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
        }
```

**to**

```
if (!$result) {
        printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
        }
```

Comment: Do you really think that a comment that spots a silly syntax typo and doesn't answer the question deserve *any* voting? What about  being helpful to the *site* yourself and vote to close instead ot trying to answer not-a-real-question?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a basic thing "**;**" **A semi colon** plus "**VALUES**"

```
$queryorder = "INSERT INTO `order`
(`orderone`, `ordertwo`, `orderthree`) VALUES ('$one','$two','$three')";
```

Comment: your above code will through error :) i leave to you to find the answer of 'why'?

Comment: Good finding @RishabhRaj :)

Comment: ya kirk just made it more terrible :)

Comment: Now the faults are updated in my post. I was written good in the actual file. Still no luck with the insert_id still getting NULL. Anyone has a suggestion?